# Text drops down with smaller window

Tags: css, ipad

I've adapted some CSS to use in a website and can't quite figure out why one aspect of the page is acting the way that it is acting.  Basically, when I shrink my window below a certain size horizontally, all of the text "drops down".  This becomes an issue if a user is viewing my website through an ipad with vertical orientation.  You can view this issue [here](http://www.itsmorethanatextbook.com/books/book_1/homepage/index.php).  I'm hoping to make it so that even if the window gets smaller, the placement of my text remains intact.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the area does not have enough space to put both the side navigation and content on one line. Make it automatically adjust the page's width when it exceeds certain decrements of width. **This code is an example,** and it is highly unlikely for it to work. If I could see the CSS more clearly, then I could provide the exact code.

```
@media all and (max-width:960px) { /* Assuming the #wrapper is 960px across */
    #content {width:560px;} /* As opposed to 720px */
}
```

### Edit

The content drops down at exactly 980px, so you have to shrink the width after there.

```
@media all and (max-width:980px) {
    #container {width:520px;}
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it made the entire container smaller; I actually want to keep the navigation bar where it is as well as the content (the book text), but less of the text should show.

Comment: I've played around some more and am now on the right track; I have never implemented "responsive design" and now understand what your code is trying to accomplish.  The problem was that my text-content was using a class (.col-780) which gave it a fixed percent for the width.  When the window size dropped below 980px, there was too much text, so the text dropped down.  So, what I need to do is adjust the width of .col-780 to account for the smaller window.  I can definitely do this via jquery.  However, is there a css solution, which readjusts .col-780, based on the side of its div?

Answer (score 0):

div#content "drops down" because is set to be `float:right` which means when you resize the browser the content div to going to be moved with the flow of the page as it gets narrower.

try styling `div#wrapper` as `white-space:nowrap` and `div#nav_left` and `div#content` both `white-space:normal`